# Override the builtin types methods

Tags: python, python-3.x

In the inheritance chapter of "fluent_python", it demonstrate an example as alternative to override the builtin types

```
In [50]: class AnswerDict2(collections.UserDict):
    ...:     def __getitem__(self, key):
    ...:         return 42
    ...:
```

It works properly as the author's intention

```
In [60]: ad = AnswerDict2(a="foo")

In [61]: ad["a"]
Out[61]: 42

In [62]: d = {}

In [63]: d.update(ad)

In [64]: d
Out[64]: {'a': 42}
```

However, the original of ad is still not overrode:

```
In [65]: ad
Out[65]: {'a': 'foo'}
```

How could let it be:

```
In [65]: ad
Out[65]: {'a': 42}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override the `__init__` method instead:

```
import collections
class AnswerDict2(collections.UserDict):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        for key in kwargs:
            self[key] = 42
```

so that:

```
ad = AnswerDict2(a="foo")
print(ad)
```

would output:

```
{'a': 42}
```